# How can I combine columns from two tables and an alias created by a conditional statement?

Tags: mysql

This approach doesn't work because it creates a syntax error.

```
SELECT A.Field1, A.Field2, B.Field3, B.Field4, Field5,
IF(A.SomeField = "","No","Yes") AS Field5;
FROM Atable A, Btable B
WHERE A.Field1 = B.FieldX;
```

Comment: BTW, better to use an explicit INNER JOIN rather than the old-fashioned ',' syntax. Also, can you post what you want as output and what you are getting that 'doesn't work'?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I changed the text to be more explicit about a syntax error. Getting these questions right is a little difficult for someone wading into such uncharted waters like me. The MCVE can be more extensive than my example, but once it's a syntax error, would my question normally be sufficient? Perhaps I could have added the error code, but that's now lost because the answer solved the problem. Do you think it's still worth the down vote?

Comment: IMO anyone posting that they got an error should quote that error in full. (Also, you're using the wrong quotes, at least if you have `set quoted_identifier on`, which you should!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `CASE WHEN`

```
SELECT A.Field1, A.Field2, B.Field3, B.Field4, 
    CASE WHEN A.Field1 = "" 
    THEN 'NO' ELSE 'YES' END AS Field5
FROM Atable A
JOIN Btable B on B.FieldX = A.Field1
```

Comment: Excellent! Thanks much.

Comment: You are welcome! You can accept is as the answer. Thanks.